# Trigger event keyDown on Contenteditable element (testing + react + jest + enzyme)

Tags: reactjs, testing, contenteditable, jestjs, enzyme

I am using enzyme + jest to test react App, is it possible to trigger onKeyDown event on contetnteditable span element?

```
<span id = 'name' contenteditable = 'true'> Editable text </span>
```

I tried:

```
result.find('#name').simulate('keyDown', { key: 'm', keyCode: 77, which: 77 });,
```

but it did not work. Element content stayed unchanged.

Comment: Element code: 
    `<span id = 'name' contenteditable = 'true'> Editable text </span>

`

Comment: You have no click handler on the `span`. What do you expect, what should change?

Comment: All major browsers do not need onClick handler for focusing on contentEditable element. I want to trigger keyDown event, like when a user types text in contentEditable element.

Comment: Here you can see link for this Q, I wrote on enzyme github page https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/927

Comment: This will be closed. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how enzyme works. It can only simulate events that were added in react explicit. From the docs

> Even though the name would imply this simulates an actual event,
>   .simulate() will in fact target the component's prop based on the
>   event you give it. For example, .simulate('click') will actually get
>   the onClick prop and call it.